# Kafka Streams persistent store error: the state store, may have migrated to another instance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams with Spring Boot. In my use case when I receive customer event from other microservice I need to store in **customer** materialized view and when I receive **order** event, I  need to join customer and order then store in **customer-order** materialized view. To achieve this  I created persistent key-value store **customer-store** and [updating this when a new event comes](https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kafkastream/service/EventsListener.java).

```
    StoreBuilder customerStateStore = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("customer"),Serdes.String(), customerSerde).withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>());
streamsBuilder.addStateStore(customerStateStore);
KTable<String,Customer> customerKTable=streamsBuilder.table("customer",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),customerSerde));
    customerKTable.foreach(((key, value) -> System.out.println("Customer from Topic: "+value)));
```

Configured Topology, Streams and started streams object. When I try to access store using ReadOnlyKeyValueStore, I got the following exception, even though I stored some objects few moments ago

```
streams.start();
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Customer> customerStore = streams.store("customer", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
System.out.println("customerStore.approximateNumEntries()-> " + customerStore.approximateNumEntries());
```

Code uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing) for reference. Appreciate your help.

Exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: the state store, customer, may have migrated to another instance.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.QueryableStoreProvider.getStore(QueryableStoreProvider.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.store(KafkaStreams.java:1043)
    at com.kafkastream.service.EventsListener.main(EventsListener.java:94)
```

Comment: Why do you not use a `join()` operator?

Comment: I started with leftJoin and forgot to replace with `join()`. I will change it to join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state store needs some time to be prepared usually. The simplest approach is like below. (code from the official document)

```
public static <T> T waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(final String storeName,
                                              final QueryableStoreType<T> queryableStoreType,
                                              final KafkaStreams streams) throws InterruptedException {
  while (true) {
    try {
      return streams.store(storeName, queryableStoreType);
    } catch (InvalidStateStoreException ignored) {
      // store not yet ready for querying
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
  }
}
```

You can find additional info in the document.
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#interactive-queries

Comment: I tried to use your code, but I got following exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR.

Comment: did you call above method after calling streams.start() ?

Comment: Yes. Please look at  Test class at line 140  https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing/blob/master/src/test/java/com/kafkastream/TestConsumer.java

Comment: I closed my IDE and opened. Now, I see my code stays forever on `waitUntilStoreIsQueryable()` method.

Comment: i feel like this may have been introduced with confluenct 4.0+, kafka 1.10 as im seeing similar issue, but only for streams that subscribe to multiple connect topics.  it's never ever able find the store for these types of streams; other streams are fine.  if i wipe the logs, store, offset and restart, works fine. not a solution though

Comment: I've looked at your code briefly. If you run your test code `queryCustomerStore`, it doesn't have any topology and code that will make statestore. Move some code from `consumeCustomerEvent` into `queryCustomerStore` about making state store and build topology stuff and try it again.

Comment: @yongsung.yoon I am not using `queryCustomerStore` for testing. I am using `consumeAllCustomerAndOrderEvents()` method, this has all the code. Let me commit latest update

Comment: @yongsung.yoon mik01010 solution worked for me. But I have one basic question. In my code when I receive `Customer` event, I am storing this in a materialized view. When I receive `Order` event, I am joining Order with existing Customers. Here is the problem, when I receive `Order` event, customer KTable returns nothing even though I stored previous events in customer-store materialized view. As a result of this, my join operation becomes useless. Is this the valid behavior of Kafka Materialized view?

Comment: It could happen for various reasons and depends on your topology. Most common mistake in joining KStream and KTable is caused by topic key and partition. You wrote that `Customer` is stored in the materialized view. It is probably stored with custom id as a key and key decides partitions. Normal `KTable` in each task only has some part of data that belong to assigned partition. If you want to lookup all customers in all tasks, you should use Global Ktable. Or you can re-publish your Order event into another topic with customer id as a key. And join new topic with Customer order table.

Comment: P.S Using Global KTable will cause quite big overhead because it just receive all paritions on each Kakfka Streams instance. Namely you will receive all data for each your machine.

Comment: @yongsung.yoon If you look at my code, that's what I am doing. When I receive order event, I am rekeying order with `customerId` and sending to `customer-to-ktable-topic` topic and building table from it. After this, I am joining both tables. My issue as described above, `customer table` returns nothing when order event arrives. I am not sure whats going on. I created another issue for this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50034855/ktable-unable-fetch-data-from-materialized-view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169894/discussion-between-jadda-and-yongsung-yoon).